# Accessing samba shares with gio in python

Tags: python, authentication, gnome, samba, gio

I am trying to make a simple command line client for accessing shares via the Python bindings of gio (yes, the main requirement is to use gio).

I can see that comparing with it's predecessor gnome-vfs, it provides some means to do authentication stuff (subclassing `MountOperation`), and even some methods which are quite specific to samba shares, like `set_domain()`.

But I'm stuck with this code:

```
import gio

fh = gio.File("smb://server_name/")
```

If that server needs authentication, I suppose that a call to `fh.mount_enclosing_volume()` is needed, as this methods takes a `MountOperation` as a parameter. The problem is that calling this methods does nothing, and the logical `fh.enumerate_children()` (to list the available shares) that comes next fails.

Anybody could provide a working example of how this would be done with gio ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following appears to be the minimum code needed to mount a volume:

```
def mount(f):
    op = gio.MountOperation()
    op.connect('ask-password', ask_password_cb)
    f.mount_enclosing_volume(op, mount_done_cb)

def ask_password_cb(op, message, default_user, default_domain, flags):
    op.set_username(USERNAME)
    op.set_domain(DOMAIN)
    op.set_password(PASSWORD)
    op.reply(gio.MOUNT_OPERATION_HANDLED)

def mount_done_cb(obj, res):
    obj.mount_enclosing_volume_finish(res)
```

(Derived from [gvfs-mount](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gvfs/tree/programs/gvfs-mount.c).)

In addition, you may need a glib.MainLoop running because GIO mount functions are asynchronous. See the gvfs-mount source code for details.