# Using gtk dialog chooser widget to list files of a remote destination

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, paramiko

Well the question says it all.I am trying to create a file transfer application using python, and pygtk for UI.Most of the code is complete,the only problem being the UI for listing remote host's file list.

I really like the Gtk Dialog Chooser widget,and already use it to list the local machine file list.I really would like to use the same widget to list files of the remote destination.Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the *paramiko* tag, I assume you're using that to work with SSH. The GTK+ file chooser can't be populated manually, so what you're trying to do is not possible.

However, most GTK+ packages come with [GIO+GVFS](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/unstable/ch01.html) [1]. This is a completely separate framework from Paramiko, but you should be able to use both (or even completely drop Paramiko).

[1] One big caveat is that GVFS still doesn't exist in Windows (and probably won't ever exist). If you need to support Windows, you *may* be able to use the older [GnomeVFS](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gnome-vfs-2.0/), but I don't know how.

To use GIO with the GTK+ file chooser:

1. `uri = 'sftp://foo.example.org/a/b/c'`
2. [Mount the volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991206/accessing-samba-shares-with-gio-in-python/2051628#2051628) (or you can run `gvfs-mount` to test first). To use the linked code:

   1. `f = gio.File(uri)`
   2. `mount(f)`
3. `file_chooser.set_current_folder_uri(uri)`